# mysql OrderBy not using index

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by

I am using mysql.
And create index on 'playCount' 'desc' in table D.
However, it did not apply.
So, I create index on 'aId ASC, playCount DESC' in table D.
But, it did not apply too.

Order by is so slow, please tell me how to create an index on my code.

```sql
explain SELECT `A`.`id` AS `id`, `A`.`title` AS `title`, `A`.`img` AS `img`
FROM `A` `A` 
INNER JOIN `B` `B` ON `B`.`aId`=`A`.`id`  
INNER JOIN `C` `C` ON `C`.`id`=`B`.`cId`  
LEFT JOIN `D` `D` ON `D`.`aId`=`A`.`id` 
GROUP BY `A`.`id` 
ORDER BY `D`.`playCount` DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: sorry.. I edit code

Comment: None index can be used for ORDER BY improvement in this query, temptable sorting will be used always.

Comment: Just FYI, you can get rid of all those `tick` marks.  You should only need them if an issue such as a reserved word, otherwise looks really cluttered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be at least 2 reasons why the `ORDER BY` may be ignored.

*That* query will be performed this way:

1. Join together all valid combinations (based on the `ONs`) of rows among those tables.  This generates a potentially large temp table.  This temp table will include a bunch of columns -- title, etc.
2. Perform the `GROUP BY`.  This probably requires sorting the temp table above.  This may shrink back down to a smaller temp table.  Since this `GROUP BY` must be performed *before* the `ORDER BY`, no index relating to the `ORDER BY` can help.
3. Sort (again) to get the desired `ORDER BY`.
4. Deliver the first 10 rows.  This effectively tosses any bulky thing (title?) (except for the first 10) that had been carried around since step 1.

If there were a `WHERE` clause, the addition of an `INDEX` might help.

`INDEX(aId ASC, playCount DESC)` -- Well, I need to ask what version of MySQL you are using.  Mixing ASC and DESC has always been allowed, and the sorting has always worked correctly.  But `DESC` has been ignored in the index until version 8.0.  (Still, as I have already pointed out, the index cannot be used.)

If you want to discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, the approximate size of each table, and whether the tables are related 1:1 or many:many or many:1.

Comment: thanks. I will study as you answered!